# how can I prevent the browser to cancel the XMLHttpRequest before reaching 5 minutes in angular 6?

Tags: angular, browser

I have a restful webservice which takes more than 2 minutes to respond.Calling this service in my angular application, raise 
quite a few times the following error

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

 message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
```

The restfull service is an external API, I can't do optimization on it. To solve this I tried to set an XMLHttpRequest time-out value before calling my service

```
 private addTimeout(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
    return req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('timeout', '180000')})
  }
```

It worked fine until I set the timeout more than 3 minutes. the timeout was ignored.

So how can I prevent the browser to cancel the XMLHttpRequest before reaching 5 minutes?

Comment: are you using nodejs from backend side?

Comment: actually this is not an issue of browser side. i face the same scenario as my service was taking 10 minutes to excute, while it was cancelled automatically after two minutes and i was using nodejs and apache tomcat and then i change the timeout thing in nodejs configuration file and then every was ok.

Comment: Thanks Farhat, you are right, this is a server side issue, i added a timeout in my conf and it is resolved. Thanks again for your help

Comment: not a problem man I am glad it helps you out.